# error in java GET / HTTP/1.1, 127.0.0.1 refuse to connect

Tags: java, sockets, http, network-programming

I have the following code:

```java
try
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
    System.out.println("wainting for clients...");
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println("Hello  client!");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String clientInput = input.readLine();
    System.out.println(clientInput);
    input.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
                
} catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

When I try to open it in my browser by typing `127.0.0.1:9090`, I get the following Error in the console:

> GET / HTTP/1.1

And in the browser I get:

> 127.0.0.1 refuse to connect

My code and output:

[image: My Code And Output]

Instructor code:

[image: Instructor Code]

Instructor output:

[image: Instructor Output]

I tried many solutions, like using different ports, and allowing the browser on firewall, but none of these solutions worked.

I could not find a solution for Java.

Comment: You might want to look at how the HTTP protocol actually works. You don't just send the data directly.

Comment: @dan1st I got the code from some video, and I followed the same steps, the video did not mention anything special. 

also do you mean how it works in java or in general ?
and what might be the problems so I can search in it, because I searched a lot but it was useless ?!

Comment: Was the tutorial about sockets in general or about HTTP?

Comment: @dan1st sockets only, It did not mention any thing about HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: [This RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3) explains how HTTP messages should be formatted. [The wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Message_format) may provide a simpler explaination.

Comment: Your code is fine for sockets but you need to add other stuff for HTTP. HTTP uses TCP under the hood but you need to follow a specific format.

Comment: but in the tutorial when the instructor runes the program he did not say any thing about HTTP, and the program worked just fine with him

Comment: It works fine for raw TCP connections but you need to send different data for HTTP (your code doesn't follow the HTTP protocol).

Comment: But how did it work with the instructor ??
I will add a picture for that in 2 mins

Comment: @dan1st Photo added

Comment: Maybe the browser of the instructor supports displaying raw messages.

Comment: Your server only accepts one connection, reads from it, writes garbage to it instead of valid HTML, and then closes the connection, closes the listening socket, and exits. Clearly it wasn't listening at the time you made the browser request, but even if it did it wouldn't have satisfied the browser. You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP correcly, and this isn't it. Too broad.

Comment: @user207421 I know that I am not using the correct implementation of HTTP, and I did not start learning it yet, It is coming in the way

Comment: @dan1st , You were right!! I tried the same browser as the instructor and it worked!, Thank you so much !   

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from @dan1st, and the answer is that only Firefox browser allows raw TCP messages